# concurrent message processing ordered chronologically

Tags: c++, qt, concurrency, message-queue

I want to optimize a message decoder written in C++ in terms of performance. The decoder is designed completely sequentially. The concept for the actual parallelization is kind of simple:

As soon as new data arrives on a certain socket, tell a thread-pool to run another thread that will decode the received message.

At the end of each thread, a method will be invoked (namely a Qt signal will be emitted) and an object created during processing will be passed.

My problem is: length and complexity of the processed messages vary, such that the order in which threads finish might differ from the order that the messages have been received. In other words, I need to serialize in place without the use of a threadsafe container.

How can I make sure that threads, as soon as they finish, call the method mentioned above in the correct chronological order without queueing them in a threadsafe container?

My first idea was to create as many mutexes as there are threads in the thread-pool and then use each mutex to send a "finished"-signal from an older thread to a newer thread.

Any comments appreciated!

Comment: Can you explain, why you can't use a threadsafe container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really don't want to use a data structure like a priority_queue or a sequence of pre-reserved buffers and block your threads instead, you can do the following:

1. Pair your message with an index that indicates its original
   position and pass it on to the thread pool.
2. Use a common (e.g. global, atomic) counter variable that indicates the last processed message.
3. Let each thread wait until this variable indicates that the previous message has been processed.
4. Pass on the produced object and increase the counter

The code would look something like this:

```
struct MsgIndexed {
    size_t idx;
    Msg msg;
};

//Single thread that receives all messages sequentially
void threadReceive() {
    for (size_t i = 1; true ; i++)
    {
        Msg m = readMsg();
        dipatchMsg(MsgIndexed{i,m});
    }
}

std::atomic<size_t> cnt=0;
//multiple worker threads that work in parallel
void threadWork() {
    while (1) {
        MsgIndexed msg = waitforMsg();
        Obj obj = processMsg(msg.msg);

        //Just for demonstration purposes. 
        //You probably don't want to use a spinlock here, but e.g. a condition variable instead     
        while (cnt != (msg.idx - 1u)) { std::this_thread::yield(); } 

        forwardObj(obj);
        cnt++;
    }
}
```

Just be aware that this is a quite inefficent solution, as your workerthreads still have to wait around after they are done with their actual work.

Comment: Thanks MikeMB, this is an amazing solution. The only thing I have to solve different is the atomic variable, because I cannot use C++11. I have to Use Qt (QThread, QtConcurrent, QThreadPool et al.). Maybe I will use a QWaitCondition. I am new to concurrency in Qt and the signal/slot mechanisms behave a little strange in this context, I have the impression that there's a lot of magic in the background.

Comment: I haven't checked, but as far as I know, c++11 and QT are not mutually exclusive, so you should be able to use atomics (I don't know whether you need them though). However, I absolutely agree that you should use a more advanced synchronization mechanism than a spinlock. Btw: don't forget to verify that your new solution is actually faster than your original one.

Comment: What do you thing about that: http://pastebin.com/7PXLLvTx I used a mutex and a wait condition. Do you see any race conditions or dead locks?

Comment: I think your code should work as expected. I'd just make sure that processData() is very simple and doesn't lock other mutexes. Depending on how you implement the communication betweeen your DecoderTask and whatever task recieves the processed object, it could be more efficient and even less error prone, to put the unlock() direclty after the while loop and replace seqProcessed with an atomic - assuming wakeAll() doesn't have to be protected by a mutex (it's not necessary for c++11's conditionVariables). But thats speculation on my part and needs to be verified.